# Apache Authentication of an IP Address

Tags: apache, authentication

I'm new to apache so sorry if this is a newbie question.  I have a reverse proxy set-up (and working) with the following code which includes a working authentication:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ProxyPass /PIZZA/ http://localhost:3636/PIZZA/
ProxyPassReverse /PIZZA/ http://localhost:3636/PIZZA/
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location /PIZZA/>
AuthUserFile /etc/USER_PWD/PIZZA_PWD
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The above authentication is working if I go do my /PIZZA/ url.

However, if I type in the source IP address for the same url (ex: 192.168.1.11:3636/PIZZA/) the webpage loads without the need for authentication.

My question, is there a way to authenticate the specific source ip address? Something like the following (which doesn't work)?

```
<Location http://192.168.1.11:3636/PIZZA/>
AuthUserFile /etc/USER_PWD/PIZZA_PWD
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</Location>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You do _not_ want to implement an additional authentication in that backend server listening to port 3636. You simply want to _block_ all requests to that port that do _not_ original from the system itself on network level. So use your 
network package filter ("firewall") for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  It was probably a rookie error trying to do the second authentication.

Arkascha - your answer pointed me in the right direction and I got it to work.  I essentially just blocked access to the port in the firewall and that worked.

I would have never figured this out without your pointing me in the right direction so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd case, you're not even accessing Apache, so no Apache configuration is going to make any difference.  If you want the backend server to only accept connections from your proxy server, you'll have to configure the backend server appropriately (or count on it being inaccessible over TCP)